Breaking down 「お間違えないでしょうか。」
In this video 「お間違えないでしょうか。」  was spoken by restaurant staff after confirming a customer's order.  I'm unsure which breakdown of this phrase is correct:

お+間違え is a noun. ない = ありません, and the speaker omits the が/は particle between the two: お間違え(が)ないでしょうか。

間違えない = 間違えません. Then for keigo it acts like a noun, meaning it can add お and behave similar to the "verb nouns" in the examples below (examples given because I'm still a bit shaky on keigo "verb nouns").



登山電車をご利用のお客様は、正面右側、3番のホームへお進みください。


店内でお召し上がりですか。

I know it's nitpicky but I'm really trying to understand keigo on a deeper level, so thanks in advance.

Did you see this in subtitles or did you hear it and convert it to writing based on what you heard? If the latter, was it possible it was actually お間違いないでしょうか? People do say お間違えないでしょうか as well, but I think some would regard it as malformed keigo, so it seems less likely to show up in a script, etc.

@Leebo 間違い and 間違え both sound fine to me in this context. The former is from 間違う and the latter from 間違える. Although 間違い is almost always preferred as a noun meaning "mistake", in the context of forming keigo after お, both are common.

@naruto Ah, I remembered seeing a comment that insinuated otherwise, but I appreciate the correction.

@Leebo - I would understand お間違えないでしょうか as asking （あなたは）間違えていませんか and お間違いないでしょうか as 間違いはありませんか. The former does sound like wrong keigo to me.

Well, according to this NHK survey, お間違いありませんか is not safe anyway, and elderly people might confuse it with 間違っていませんか and get upset. Personally I have never felt any problem whether it's お間違い or お間違え, but this seems more subjective than I thought.

If you've got the お～ or ご～ prefix, you should know that these only attach to nouns (including the noun-ified stems of verbs), so this construction must be #1 in your two options above. :)
For お間違【まちが】えないでしょうか, this must be parsed as:

honorific prefix お～
noun 間違【まちが】え ("mistake")
negative copula ない ("there isn't, it isn't")
polite copula with suppositive ending でしょう ("isn't it the case that...", implying a desire for confirmation from the listener)

Looking at the semantics of keigo, polite language in pretty much any language involves indirectness.  By noun-ifying (or more properly, nominalizing) verbs, we add some indirection by taking the emphasis off of the person doing the action.  So rather than the very-blunt 店内【てんない】で食【く】うか ("youse eatin' in da store?"), we make this less blunt — less direct — by nominalizing the action (as well as by using fancier synonyms for the verb in many cases): 店内【てんない】でお召【め】し上【あ】がりですか ("is it that the consumption of comestibles will be in the shop?").

The translation seemed a bit... overdone, until I actually thought about it. I'm grinning now.
